# wicket - text field with formate that support 1,000 instead of 1000

Tags: jakarta-ee, wicket

i would like to show in the client the string 1,000 where the acutall value is int x = 1000 as integer
how can I achive this ?

I am trying to do it by genrating new class
myTextFiels 
which would have

```
@Override
public <C> IConverter<C> getConverter(Class<C> type) {
    IConverter<C> converter = super.getConverter(type);
    if (converter instanceof AbstractDecimalConverter<?>) {

        ((AbstractDecimalConverter<?>) converter).getNumberFormat(getLocale()).setGroupingUsed(true);
    } else {
        ((AbstractIntegerConverter<?>) converter).getNumberFormat(getLocale()).setGroupingUsed(true);
    }

    return converter;
}
```

but this does not seem to work , what am i missing

Comment: Use a jQuery plugin for that like autoNumeric: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: How's your TextField defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `getNumberFormat()` on the converter, it doesn't return a reference to the `NumberFormat` instance that the converter will use, but rather a clone of the instance:

```
@Override
public NumberFormat getNumberFormat(final Locale locale)
{
    NumberFormat numberFormat = numberFormats.get(locale);
    if (numberFormat == null)
    {
        numberFormat = newNumberFormat(locale);
        setNumberFormat(locale, numberFormat);
    }
    return (NumberFormat)numberFormat.clone();
}
```

This is taken directly from the code of `AbstractDecimalConverter`. So to achieve what you want you should in your code do the following:

```
AbstractDecimalConverter castConverter = (AbstractDecimalConverter<?>) converter;
NumberFormat newNumberFormatForLocale = castConverter.getNumberFormat(getLocale());
newNumberFormatForLocale.setGroupingUsed(true);
castConverter.setNumberFormat(getLocale(), newNumberFormatForLocale);
```

**However** there's something you need to understand when you're doing this: the converter you get from the `super.getConverter` is retrieved using the `Application`'s global converter locator. By default, the converter locator contains a singleton converter for every type.

What this means is that if you change this format at some point in one of your pages this way, then all of the other pages for that locale will use that formatting as well. I would imagine that this could be okay potentially, but if it isn't then instead of changing the `NumberFormat` on the converter you retrieve from the `super.getConverter()` I would create a new instance of the `AbstractDecimalConverter` in the `getConverter` method with the required `NumberFormat` set on it and return that instead, in which case the global singleton remains intact.

Do reply if you want anything elaborated at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the prettiest solution but here's a bit of code to solve it

```
public static String numberformatter(int n){
    String number = "";

    int leftpart = n / 1000;
    int rightpart = n - (leftpart * 1000);
    number = rightpart + number;

    while(leftpart > 0){
        int old = leftpart;
        leftpart = old / 1000;
        rightpart = old - (leftpart * 1000);
        number = rightpart + "," + number;
    }

    return number;
}
```